# HostKeyAlgorithms in centos6.5

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

Although I mention `ssh-dss` for `HostKeyAlgorithms` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. ssh-rsa key pair can be used to login!

```
     HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [OpenSSH Legacy Options](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) and [OpenSSH 7.0 & greater disable ssh-dss by default](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/OpenSSH_7_0_greater_disable_ssh_dss_by_default).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Some useful info on the above issue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/ssh-key-type-rsa-dsa-ecdsa-are-there-easy-answers-for-which-to-choose-when)

In practice, a RSA key will work everywhere. ECDSA support is newer, so some old client or server may have trouble with ECDSA keys. A DSA key used to work everywhere, as per the SSH standard (RFC 4251 and subsequent), but this changed recently: OpenSSH 7.0 and higher no longer accept DSA keys by default.